# How to Validating Entry Widget ? Python

Tags: validation, user-interface, tkinter, textbox, widget

I am new to Python and would like to implement a simple Employee Management System (as shown on the attached photo) that do the following functionality

• A GUI for entering, viewing, and exporting employee data. **(Already completed)**

• The ability to export data into an Excel or csv file. **(Not done yet)**

• The ability to import all data from an Excel or csv file into the GUI.

Here is an example of the GUI

[image]

And Here is the CSV File

```
    Fullname            Age Gender  Position              Phone Number  Address
    Ali Talib           59  Male    Vice-Chancellor       1752555555    UK-London
    Afaf Neamah         23  Female  Manager               7912394404    UK-Plymouth
    Hussein Neamah      22  Male    Head of Department    7335952523    UK-London
    Estabraq Aldalboos  33  Female  Engineer              7575252324    UK-Plymouth
    Nathan Clarke       45  Male    Deputy Head of School 7916682090    UK-London
    Neamah AL-Naffakh   37  Male    Lecturer              7817792202    UK-Plymouth
```

**I need to develop the code to do the following**

•  **Validating Entry Widget** (i.e., accepting valid input for each text box). For example, accept numbers only for Age, and mobile number and visa versa (i.e., doesnt accept number for name, gender, position)- **Show message box for invalid input**

**Here is the code**

```
    import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def load_data(path):      # Load data from csv file at program start.
    reader = csv.reader(open(path))
    return list(reader)[1:]

window=Tk()
window.geometry("800x500+0+0")
window.title("Employee Management System")
window.maxsize(width=800,height=500)
window.minsize(width=800,height=500)
FILEPATH = '/Users/nhal-naffakh/Desktop/Desktop/Sec-Interview/Data.csv'

main_lst = load_data(FILEPATH)  # Load csv data into `main_lst`


def view():
  index = listbox1.curselection()[0]
  NameLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][0])
  AgeLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][1])
  GenderLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][2])
  PositionLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][3])
  AddressLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][4])

def OpenFile():
    pass

def Add():
   name = Nametxt.get()  # get the name of new entry
   lst = [name, Agetxt.get(), Gendertxt.get(), Positiontxt.get(), Numbertxt.get(), Addresstxt.get()]
   main_lst.append(lst)
   listbox1.insert(len(List_of_Name), name)  # add it to the listbox list
   List_of_Name.append(name)  # store it in the list of names
   messagebox.showinfo("Information","The data has been added successfully")

def Save():
   with open(FILEPATH,"w") as file:
      writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
      writer.writerow(["Fullname","Age","Gender","Position","Phone Number","Address"])
      writer.writerows(main_lst)  #  now when it writes to file it will contain all the data.
      messagebox.showinfo("Information","Saved succesfully")

def Clear():
   Nametxt.delete(0,END)
   Agetxt.delete(0,END)
   Gendertxt.delete(0,END)
   Positiontxt.delete(0,END)
   Numbertxt.delete(0,END)
   Addresstxt.delete(0,END)

def Exit():
    wayOut = messagebox.askyesno("Employee Management System", "Do you want to exit the system")
    if wayOut > 0:
        Save()  # Added a call to save upon exiting.
        window.destroy()
        return

List_of_Name=[]
for x in list(range(0,len(main_lst))):
    List_of_Name.append(main_lst[x][0])

var = StringVar(value=List_of_Name)
listbox1 = Listbox(window, listvariable=var)
listbox1.grid(row=3,column=0)

buttonView = Button(text="ViewRecord", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4,
                    font=('ariel',12,'bold'), width=8, fg='black',
                    bg="dark gray", command=view).grid(row=3,column=1)
NameLabel = Label(window,text="FullName").grid(row=5,column=0,sticky="w")
AgeLabel=Label(window,text="Age").grid(row=6,column=0,sticky="w")
GenderLabel=Label(window,text="Gender").grid(row=7,column=0,sticky="w")
PositionLabel=Label(window,text="Position").grid(row=8,column=0,sticky="w")
AddressLabel=Label(window,text="Address").grid(row=9,column=0,sticky="w")
NameLabel2=Label(window,text="")
NameLabel2.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky="w")
AgeLabel2=Label(window,text="")
AgeLabel2.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky="w")
GenderLabel2=Label(window,text="")
GenderLabel2.grid(row=7,column=1,sticky="w")
PositionLabel2=Label(window,text="")
PositionLabel2.grid(row=8,column=1,sticky="w")
AddressLabel2=Label(window,text="")
AddressLabel2.grid(row=9,column=1,sticky="w")
Namelabel3=Label(window,text="Full Name",
                    font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg="white",
                    bg="dark blue",).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
Nametxt = Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4,width=22, justify='left')
Nametxt.grid(row=0,column=1)

Agelabel3=Label(window,text="Age",font=("ariel",12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue",).grid(row=0,column=2)
Agetxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Agetxt.grid(row=0,column=3)

GenderLabel3=Label(window,text="Gender",font=('ariel',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w")
Gendertxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Gendertxt.grid(row=1,column=1)

PositionLabel3=Label(window,text="Position",font=('ariel',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue").grid(row=1,column=2,sticky="w")
Positiontxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Positiontxt.grid(row=1,column=3)

NumberLabel3=Label(window,text="Mob Number",font=('ariel',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="w")
Numbertxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Numbertxt.grid(row=2,column=1)

AddressLabel3=Label(window,text="Address",font=('ariel',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue").grid(row=2,column=2,sticky="w")
Addresstxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Addresstxt.grid(row=2,column=3)

#  Button
LoadButton=Button(text="Load File", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black',bg="dark gray", command=OpenFile).grid(row=3,column=2)
AddButton=Button(text="Add Record", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black',bg="dark gray",command=Add).grid(row=3,column=3)
SaveButton=Button(text="Save", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black',bg="dark gray",command=Save).grid(row=4,column=1)
ClearButton=Button(text="Clear", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black',bg="dark gray",command=Clear).grid(row=4,column=2)
ExitButton=Button(text="Exit", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black', bg="dark gray",command=Exit).grid(row=4,column=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you asking to code it for you? Where is your attempt and what is wrong with what you tried.

Comment: Dear @DelriusEuphoria I have tried the following but it doesnt work                                
    `def callback(input):
         if input.isdigit():
        print(input)
        return True
                        
    elif input is "":
        print(input)
        return True

    else:
        print(input)
        return False`

Comment: Any code has to be included within the question, its hard to understand from comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validating the data You can place a text validation function with the `Add Record` button callback, so that when the user clicks the add record it first checks each entry field to make sure that certain criteria are met.

For example, I added a validate_text function that is called on each entry widgets text when the add record button is clicked.  It first makes sure the entry isn't left blank, then it checks for numbers only for the age and numbers field, and then checks the rest to make sure there are no numbers in the text.  If any of the conditions are true then it shows an error messagebox and no record is added to the main_lst or the csv file. Otherwise it adds the record to the main_lst and to the gui.

```
import csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def load_data(path):      # Load data from csv file at program start.
    reader = csv.reader(open(path))
    return list(reader)[1:]

window=Tk()
window.geometry("800x500+0+0")
window.title("Employee Management System")
window.maxsize(width=800,height=500)
window.minsize(width=800,height=500)
FILEPATH = 'data.csv'

main_lst = load_data(FILEPATH)  # Load csv data into `main_lst`


def view():
  index = listbox1.curselection()[0]
  NameLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][0])
  AgeLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][1])
  GenderLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][2])
  PositionLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][3])
  AddressLabel2.config(text=main_lst[index][4])

def OpenFile():
    pass


def validate_text(field, text):
    if not text:
        messagebox.showinfo("Invalid Entry","Values cannot be left blank.")
        return False
    elif field in ["number", "age"]:
        if not text.isnumeric():
            messagebox.showinfo("Invalid Entry", f"{field.title()} must be numeric.")
            return False
    elif not all([not i.isdigit() for i in text]):
        messagebox.showinfo("Invalid Entry", f"Numbers not permitted in {field.title()} field.")
        return False
    return True

def Add():
    entries = {"name": Nametxt, "age": Agetxt, "gender": Gendertxt, "position": Positiontxt, "number": Numbertxt,"address": Addresstxt}
    values = []
    for key, val in entries.items():
        text = val.get()
        if not validate_text(key, text):
            return
        values.append(text)
    main_lst.append(values)
    listbox1.insert(len(List_of_Name), values[0])  # add it to the listbox list
    List_of_Name.append(values[0])  # store it in the list of names
    messagebox.showinfo("Information","The data has been added successfully")

def Save():
   with open(FILEPATH,"w") as file:
      writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
      writer.writerow(["Fullname","Age","Gender","Position","Phone Number","Address"])
      writer.writerows(main_lst)  #  now when it writes to file it will contain all the data.
      messagebox.showinfo("Information","Saved succesfully")

def Clear():
   Nametxt.delete(0,END)
   Agetxt.delete(0,END)
   Gendertxt.delete(0,END)
   Positiontxt.delete(0,END)
   Numbertxt.delete(0,END)
   Addresstxt.delete(0,END)

def Exit():
    wayOut = messagebox.askyesno("Employee Management System", "Do you want to exit the system")
    if wayOut > 0:
        Save()  # Added a call to save upon exiting.
        window.destroy()
        return

List_of_Name=[]
for x in list(range(0,len(main_lst))):
    List_of_Name.append(main_lst[x][0])

var = StringVar(value=List_of_Name)
listbox1 = Listbox(window, listvariable=var)
listbox1.grid(row=3,column=0)

buttonView = Button(text="ViewRecord", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4,
                    font=('ariel',12,'bold'), width=8, fg='black',
                    bg="dark gray", command=view).grid(row=3,column=1)
NameLabel = Label(window,text="FullName").grid(row=5,column=0,sticky="w")
AgeLabel=Label(window,text="Age").grid(row=6,column=0,sticky="w")
GenderLabel=Label(window,text="Gender").grid(row=7,column=0,sticky="w")
PositionLabel=Label(window,text="Position").grid(row=8,column=0,sticky="w")
AddressLabel=Label(window,text="Address").grid(row=9,column=0,sticky="w")
NameLabel2=Label(window,text="")
NameLabel2.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky="w")
AgeLabel2=Label(window,text="")
AgeLabel2.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky="w")
GenderLabel2=Label(window,text="")
GenderLabel2.grid(row=7,column=1,sticky="w")
PositionLabel2=Label(window,text="")
PositionLabel2.grid(row=8,column=1,sticky="w")
AddressLabel2=Label(window,text="")
AddressLabel2.grid(row=9,column=1,sticky="w")
Namelabel3=Label(window,text="Full Name",
                    font=('arial',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg="white",
                    bg="dark blue",).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
Nametxt = Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4,width=22, justify='left')
Nametxt.grid(row=0,column=1)

Agelabel3=Label(window,text="Age",font=("ariel",12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue",).grid(row=0,column=2)
Agetxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Agetxt.grid(row=0,column=3)

GenderLabel3=Label(window,text="Gender",font=('ariel',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w")
Gendertxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Gendertxt.grid(row=1,column=1)

PositionLabel3=Label(window,text="Position",font=('ariel',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue").grid(row=1,column=2,sticky="w")
Positiontxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Positiontxt.grid(row=1,column=3)

NumberLabel3=Label(window,text="Mob Number",font=('ariel',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="w")
Numbertxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Numbertxt.grid(row=2,column=1)

AddressLabel3=Label(window,text="Address",font=('ariel',12,'bold'),bd=3,fg='white',
                bg="dark blue").grid(row=2,column=2,sticky="w")
Addresstxt=Entry(window,font=('ariel',12),bd=4, justify='left')
Addresstxt.grid(row=2,column=3)

#  Button
LoadButton=Button(text="Load File", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black',bg="dark gray", command=OpenFile).grid(row=3,column=2)
AddButton=Button(text="Add Record", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black',bg="dark gray",command=Add).grid(row=3,column=3)
SaveButton=Button(text="Save", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black',bg="dark gray",command=Save).grid(row=4,column=1)
ClearButton=Button(text="Clear", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black',bg="dark gray",command=Clear).grid(row=4,column=2)
ExitButton=Button(text="Exit", padx=10, pady=4, bd=4, font=('ariel',12,'bold'),
                    width=8,fg='black', bg="dark gray",command=Exit).grid(row=4,column=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dear @Alexander, As always you are very supportive. Many thanks for your kindness.